# How to fix the black screen?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon, display, xvideo

i'm running linux mint 18.1 cinnamon. i have changed the primary driver of my nvidia videocard. after the reboot the splash screen is displayed and after the display is off. cinnamon is not starting. while i change to the CLI with ctrl+alt+f1. everything is ok. i have an access to the bash. how can i fix it?[image: CLI]

Comment: Welcome to U&L , can you expand the "i have changed the primary driver of my nvidia videocard" with more details?

Comment: @GAD3R in "driver manager" i changed nouveau to nvidia. and the restarted

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to run the NVIDIA installer (and also after every kernel update). Get the latest driver for your card from http://www.nvidia.de/Download/index.aspx?lang=en, make the installer executable and run it. The installer is text based and runs fine in your terminal.

Comment: there problem came after this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371104/215550