# not able to compile OpenGL code

Tags: linux-mint, opengl, mesa

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1 on my laptop and facing this problem. When I try to compile C++ program with OpenGL libraries it says:

```
$ make
g++     solsys.cpp  -lglut -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -fpermissive -o solsys
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'solsys' failed
make: *** [solsys] Error 1
```

When I try to run already compiled programs before, but on this machine it says

```
./rotation: error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I actually understand the problem is in incorrect installing of libraries, but can't solve it.

`glxino | grep OpenGL` outputs this

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

By the way, I have problems with installing Nvidia drivers on my laptop but gave up on it.

```
$lspci | grep "NVIDIA"
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglew-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglu1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (9.0.0-2.1build1).
libglu1-mesa-dev set to manually installed.
libglew-dev is already the newest version (2.0.0-5).
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
```

...

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl-mesa0:amd64                         18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                         18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64                     18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64                      18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                       18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                      18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                       18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     i386         transitional dummy package
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                        18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglapi-mesa:i386                         18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     i386         free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libgles2-mesa:amd64                        18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        transitional dummy package
ii  libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64                    18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- development files
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                         9.0.0-2.1build1                             amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa:i386                          9.0.0-2.1build1                             i386         Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64                     9.0.0-2.1build1                             amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                         18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libglx-mesa0:i386                          18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libosmesa6:amd64                           18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libosmesa6:i386                            18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     i386         Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64                 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-common-dev:amd64                      18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1                     amd64        Developer documentation for Mesa
ii  mesa-utils                                 8.4.0-1                                     amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
```

linkage:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Jan 16 19:09 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 567624 Aug 15 12:20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: OK, so you are missing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`. Does it help if you re-install `libgl1-mesa-dev`? Run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I tried to re-install, but with no success

Comment: How did you go about trying to install the NVIDIA drivers? Did you use the NVIDIA installer, or the Mint packages?

Comment: I tried with Driver Manager, but after reboot I got the blank screen. I asked about it before [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371289/how-to-fix-the-black-screen). With `.run` package the issue is with `dkms`. I can't remember exact problem message.

Comment: @StephenKitt any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i decided to ask about it on Nvidia Forum and got an answer. I'd leave here a full [thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1047200/linux/black-screen-after-installing-nvidia-driver-on-linux-mint-19-1) so anyone could understand the whole thing around it.